# HTML : Create a dropdown in cell of table

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular8

I want to create a  table in which one of the cell works as dropdown.

Some data data.field is coming from backend. I want to show it at time of rendering.

Now a fList is also coming from backend, so when someone click of the cell it should open that list as dropdown. I added the below code but it is not showing any dropdown.

```
 <tr class="dropdown" *ngFor="let data of dataList | dataPipe">

     <td class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{data.field}}
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" *ngFor="let f of fList">
             <li>{{f}}</li>
                    
         </ul>
     </td>
                
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

actually you need to loop on dropdown values not dropdown menu
in your case dropdown values are `<li>`
try this

```html
<tr class="dropdown" *ngFor="let data of dataList | dataPipe">

     <td class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{data.field}}
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li *ngFor="let f of fList" (click)="checkValue(f)">{{f}}</li>
                    
         </ul>
     </td>
                
 </tr>
```

in your `.ts file`

```js
public checkValue(value){
console.log(value)
alert(value)
}
```

this can be a better approach

```html
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let f of fList">{{f}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
onChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is showing me list  but I am not able to select any of the value from list

Comment: i am not clear about the requirement but i am editing my answer. I can help more if you make it clear what you want to do with the selected value

Comment: selected value from dropdown should be visible in cell of table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table cell with selected value from dropdown:

```
<tr class="dropdown" *ngFor="let data of dataList | dataPipe; let i = index;">

 <td class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{data.field}}
         <td class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- 
     toggle="dropdown">{{data.field}}
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li *ngFor="let f of fList" (click)="onSelect(f, i)">{{f}}</li>
                
     </ul>
 </td>

 </td>
```

```
onSelect(selectedValue, index){
this.dataList[index].field=selectedValue;
}
```